# How can i enter the output of a shell script into a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I have a shell script named script.sh when I execute it I receive the following output which is the name of a product, and the price. (The item name corresponds with the price just below it)

```
Item1
1.00
Item2
4.00
Item3
3.49
```

Each time the script is executed it may contain a different number of items. I have created a Database named prices, with a table named prices and 2 columns 'itemName' and 'Price'.

I require a script that will add the values to the database so the database should then contain:

```
ItemName | Price
-----------------
Item1 1.00
Item2 4.00
Item3 3.49
```

I require a script that I can run via a cron job that updates the prices as they may change.

How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 1):

Create text file:

```
cat > itemprice.txt

Item1
1.00
Item2
4.00
Item3
3.49
```

Create MySQL table:

```
mysql> create table itemprice (item varchar(10), price numeric(9,2));
```

Load file into table with [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html):

```
mysql> load data local infile 'itemprice.txt' 
  into table itemprice 
  fields terminated by '\n' 
  (item, price);

mysql> select * from itemprice;
+-------+-------+
| name  | price |
+-------+-------+
| Item1 |  1.00 |
| Item2 |  4.00 |
| Item3 |  3.49 |
+-------+-------+
```

Or alternatively you can do the same thing using the equivalent [mysqlimport](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlimport.html) command (which simply runs LOAD DATA INFILE for you):

```
mysqlimport --local --fields-terminated-by='\n' mydatabase itemprice.txt
```

The table it imports to matches the filename you import.

Read the documentation I linked to for more details on using LOAD DATA INFILE or mysqlimport.

Answer (score 0):

you may consider to use `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

First create temporary table tmp_items

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_items LIKE items;
```

then load data

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'your_file.txt'
INTO TABLE tmp_items
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n'
(name, price);
```

after that merge data to your source table

```
INSERT INTO items
SELECT * FROM tmp_items
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE price = VALUES(price);
```

and drop temporary table

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_items;
```

Please note that both tables needs to have PK (identity) column.